# Why do "ping undefinedhost" and "curl undefinedhost" (e.g. libc "gethostbyname") ping / contect to the local host instead of failing?

Tags: dns, glibc

I have an old Ubuntu 16.04 (LTS) installation and today noticed, that ping and curl are being told (by libc, I assume), that the IP of any unknown host is the same as the IP of the local host (e.g. "nslookup $(</etc/hostname)").

"nslookup" and "dig" correctly report "NXDOMAIN".

In `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, I have

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

`/etc/hosts` looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

`/etc/hostname`:
host1.mydomain.net

(changed from actual value)

And `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 213.133.98.98
nameserver 213.133.99.99
nameserver 213.133.100.100
```

I was totally confused today, when `curl https://undefinedhost` printed

```
curl: (51) SSL: certificate subject name (host1.mydomain.net) does not match target host name 'undefinedhost'
```

Only when I saw the output of `ping undefinedhost` I started to understand, what seems to be happening:

```
$ ping unknownhost
PING host1.mydomain.net (138.201.175.226) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from host1.mydomain.net (138.201.175.226): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.237 ms
```

Finally, `dig` also behaves as expected:

```
$ dig unresolvedhost @213.133.98.98
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> unresolvedhost @213.133.98.98
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 28972
```

Can anybody shed some light where this might be going wrong?

Comment: Reports `Could not resolve host` on all of my systems (as I think it should). Is one of the nameservers reporting a localhost address perhaps? Try `dig unresolvedhost @213.133.98.98` etc.

Comment: No, I tried that. Says `Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 22304` - no "ANSWER SECTION"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is the existence of an implicit host-name lookup domain search list in combination with the wildcard sub-domain that I have configured under the local domain that this machine is in, e.g. mydomain.net.

Citing `man resolv.conf`:

> The search list is normally determined from the local domain name; *by default, it contains* only *the local domain name*.

I have a local bind server running and my domain is registered and active. My `/etc/bind/local/db.mydomain.net` looks like this:

```
...
@   IN  SOA mydomain.net. ....
...
host1   IN  A   138.201.175.226
*   IN  CNAME   host1.mydomain.net.
....
```

Thus, this behavior is totally correct and expected. I was just confused. :-)